# calling async webmethod from jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to call a webmethod that sends an email. I can't get it to return back to the UI; I think i am causing a deadlock somewhere in here but can't seem to solve it.

**UI**

```
 var email = { "ID": "someID", "Body": "whatever" };
                var json = '{tmpEmail:' + JSON.stringify(email) + '}';
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "send.aspx/SendMessage",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: json,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (output) {
                        alert('Message Sent')
                    },
                    error: function (output) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

**WebMethod**

```
 <WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Shared Async Function SendMessage(tmpEmail As tmpEmail) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Dim _EmailID As Guid
    _EmailID = Await EmailFunctions.SendEmail(tmpEmail)
    Return "Hey it works"
End Function
```

**SendMessage Function**

```
Public Shared Async Function SendEmailLead(obj as tmpEmail) As Task(Of Guid)
 Dim PClient As New PostmarkDotNet.PostmarkClient(APIKey)
    Dim Result As PostmarkDotNet.PostmarkResponse = await PClient.SendMessageAsync(obj)
    If Result.Status = PostmarkDotNet.PostmarkStatus.Success Then
       ...
        Return LogID
    Else
        ... throw some exception
    End If
End Function
```

I'm not able to get it to return back to the caller at any point after a few minutes when i stop debugging ill get the alert of error from the ajax call.

Ive tried:

- .GetAwaiter().GetResult(); thinking if i blocked the thread at some point eventually it might actually return, it does not.
- .ConfigureAwait(false)
- http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html went over that as well

Could someone explain, why if i am using get result all the way down it would not eventually at some point return back to "hey it works".

*Edit/Update*

After additional research I am able to get it work with the following changes:

- Remove Async/Await from the webmethod that the UI is calling.
- Wrap the async function in a non-async method
- Call the wrapped function from the original webmethod

I don't understand why this works, and does this not cause a deadlock as well? I understood that it should be async/await all the way down; however i'm only able to get it to work when it is the exact opposite of that.

Additional Question: If i have logging in that function getting called is there way to fire it off in its own thread and immediately return to the UI?

Comment: Can you please add an answer to your question that has the working code?

Comment: I think the ajax handler for asp.net still cannot do async webmethod calls. So, your technique works but provides not advantage because the asp.net thread is never released while waiting. Does not help scaling.